How to organize the issuance of rights in Kubernetes IaC?
How to organize the issuance of rights in Kubernetes IaC? I have a cluster with many namespaces, developers only need rights to individual namespaces. I don’t want to do this manually, I believe that you can describe some access groups and then set up automatic deployment in GitLab.
For example, I have namespaces: ns1 and ns2, developer accounts: developer1 and developer2. There is a group of access: devs with the necessary rights.
How to describe what is needed?
I understand how to describe with manifests and execute apply, but I want to do it with IaC with automation to simply add the account name and namespace to some file and then run the auto deployment in GitLab and that’s it.
I use GitLab as CI
It is now:
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
name: devs
namespace: ns1
rules:

apiGroups:

""
resources:
pods
pods/exec
verbs:
create
get
list
update
delete


apiGroups:

""
resources:
pods/log
verbs:
get
list
watch




kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
name: devs
namespace: ns1
subjects:

kind: User
name: develop1
namespace: ns1
roleRef:
kind: Role
name: devs
apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io

